# Can functions or variables be stored inside namespaces instead of classes - C#

Tags: c#, class, namespaces

In C#, all methods of functions must be inside a class, but by default, in a new Visual C# project, it makes a class inside of a namespace. Are you able to keep all code inside a namespace instead of a class instead?

Comment: If you could add some more info to your question about *why* you want to write code into a namespace, it would perhaps help us determine where your misunderstanding lies and better advise you

Comment: When you looked at the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/namespaces/ which part was confusing? First try to read the documentation, and then let us know the part you have trouble with so we can better help you, and future readers can benefit as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Those things you mention must be inside a class, not a namespace

To try and help clear up any misunderstanding, a namespace is an organizational facility, in the same way that a folder is for organizing files. You can't open a folder in Word and write some text in it, save the text, copy the folder to another machine etc.. You have to do all that in a file, and then put the file in a folder. In the same way all the "stuff" in C# is done in a class (or enum, struct or similar) which is the corollary of a file on a hard disk. Namespaces just serve to group classes and perhaps disambiguate them if they have the same name as another class in a different namespace

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot do that. Namespaces are merely extensions to names of types and help you sort them into different categories (and to avoid naming collisions for different libraries).

In C# every method (,property) or field needs to be in a class or struct.

The closest thing to variables or methods being "just in the namespace" would be static classes, like `System.Math` which is basically a collection of math functions and constants.

Also note that type declarations (classes, structs, enums, interfaces and delegates) can also be located in the [global namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/namespace-alias-qualifier) (which is a namespace without a name) or contained as declaration within a class or a struct which makes both the struct and the class act like namespaces.

Comment: I didn't understand the System.Math bit; Math is a static class in the System namespace, it is not a namespace in and of itself.

Comment: When you create a static class in C#, it is not instantiatable, but is declared as a regular type (like any other class). However, you may use it as a collection of helper functions which in other languages like C++ would just be method declarations in a namespace.  
This way, the methods are defined as part of the class (to match the language design of C#), but work from the outside like being located in a single namespace (to match the "helper function" approach).

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the namespace as a street address that points to some form of object (probably a building, maybe with many apartments). The building that contains stuff would be similar to the class with it's content. It would not make much sense to put all stuff that would normally reside in a building just on the street (i.e. putting methods in directly in a namespace). It would not remain there for long, that is for sure :)

Answer (score 0):

C# namespaces are somewhat limited in scope compared to namespaces in languages like C++ and Go. The missing functionality is meant to be covered by the expressive classes C# offers being an OOP-first language. Partial static classes are a good example of this in action.

That being said, the reason why I answered this already resolved question is that starting with C# 9, we can now have [top-level statements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements) in a  single source file per application. Note that this feature was added to the language primarily for learning and demo purposes, and it is achieved through syntactic sugar and nothing more.